# Python regex - How to look for an arbitrary number of sentences after a digit?

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, pattern-matching

Let's say we had the following string: "1. Sentence 1. Sentence 2? Sentence 3!".
How would I go about looking for ( and returning as a string) a pattern that matches all of the following cases:

- `"1. Sentence 1."`
- `"1. Sentence 1. Sentence 2?"`
- `"1. Sentence 1. Sentence 2? Sentence 3!"`

There is always a number in front of the pattern,
but there could be any number of sentences after it.
What I've tried thus far is

```
pattern = re.compile("\d.(\s[A-Ö][^.!?]+[.!?])+?")
```

and

```
assignmentText = "".join(pattern.findall(assignment))
```

where the `join`-method is an ugly hack used to extract the string from the list returned by `findall`, since `list[0]` doesn't seem to work ( I know there will only be a single `str` in the list).
However, I only ever receive the first sentence, without the digit in front.

How could this be fixed?

Comment: Did you mean to match uppercase letters with `[A-Ö]`? It [matches all lowercase ASCII letters, too](https://regex101.com/r/jqWfua/1).

Comment: Please post your expected output as well

Comment: The expected output is one of the strings listed in the question. As for @Wiktor Stribiżew's question, yes, I would like the sentences to be grammatically correctly in the sense that the first letter should be capitalized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `(?:(?:\d+\.\s+)?[A-Z].*?[.!?]\s*)+`.

```
import re
print(re.findall(r'(?:(?:\d+\.\s+)?[A-Z].*?[.!?]\s*)+', '1. Sentence 1. Sentence 2? Sentence 3!'))
```

This outputs:

```
['1. Sentence 1. Sentence 2? Sentence 3!']
```

Or, if you prefer separating them as 3 different items in a list:

```
import re
print(re.findall(r'(?:(?:\d+\.\s+)?[A-Z].*?[.!?])', '1. Sentence 1. Sentence 2? Sentence 3!'))
```

This outputs:

```
['1. Sentence 1.', 'Sentence 2?', 'Sentence 3!']
```

Comment: This seems to have done the trick. I can then use `join` to extract the actual string.

Comment: Just mind `[A-Z]` only matches ASCII capitalized letters.